# How to get "Appendix" and <appendix name> on same line

Tags: appendices

Is it possible to get "Appendix X" and  on the same line, maybe with a colon after the appendix identifier letter?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{CHapter one name}
\chapter{Chapter two name two}
\appendix
\chapter{Theory}
\section{Some theory}
\section{Some other theory}
\chapter{Method}
\section{LOLZ}
\section{ROLF}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the compiled PDF writes:

```
Appendix A

Theory

A.1 Some Theory
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
Appendix A: Theory

A.1 Some Theory
```

Comment: The short answer is yes, but not easily.  The whole idea of treating appendices as chapters is a kluge.  Yes, it saves a counter and reuses some code, but often causes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way, with `titlesec` and `apptools`. Appendix chapters are placed at to the top of the page, but the spacing parameters can be changed at will:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\LARGE\bfseries}{\appendixname~\thechapter:}{0.333em}{}%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one name}
\chapter{Chapter two name two}

\appendix
\chapter{Theory}
\section{Some theory}
\section{Some other theory}
\chapter{Method}
\section{LOLZ}
\section{ROLF}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to this in order to make more available space for large pictures in the appendix. Now, there's a large gap on top of the page. Any suggestions on how to make more out of the page size in the appendix only?

Comment: It's easy. See my updated answer, and adapt spacing lengths to your needs.