# How to write Appendix and its name on the same line in IEEEtran?

Tags: line-breaking, appendices, ieeetran

I would like to write

```
Appendix A: Proof of Theorem 1
```

in IEEEtran but what I am getting is

```
Appendix A 
Proof of Theorem 1
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}\maketitle

\begin{appendices}
\section{Proof of Theorem 1}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239160/how-to-get-appendix-and-appendix-name-on-same-line) but it is for report with chapter and not for IEEEtran.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the default behaviour for [`IEEEtran`](//ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) - adding a line break between the section heading and title within the . A quick fix would be to grab the forced line break - `\\*` - and insert a `:` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{An Author}
\maketitle

\begin{appendices}
\section{Proof of Theorem 1}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage

% Grab forced line break - \\* - and replace with :
\renewcommand{\thesectiondis}[2]{\Alph{section}:}

\section{Proof of Theorem 2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```